# How to Print Using Docx4j

Tags: java, printing, docx4j

I'm using Docx4j to create an MS Word document (.docx). Once this document is created, is there any way to print it? I didn't see anything in Docx4j's documentation and am assuming I have to convert the docx to pdf and print it from there.

Is there a better way? Did I miss a Docx4j PRINT feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing is outside the scope of docx4j.

So you have 3 main options:

- print the docx, using some application which is able to do that; see for example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19118/Printing-a-Word-Document-using-Word-Automation
- convert to pdf, then print that. Depending on your fidelity requirements you could do the conversion using the XSL-FO based conversion in docx4j, or you could use Plutext's better PDF Converter
- convert to (X)HTML, then print that.  Docx4j includes HTML output.